# What values should I use for light paths?

Tags: rendering, light

In a relatively simple interior room, what value do I need to use for a good-looking render?

[image: Render setting]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no works-for-everybody setting. Basically it's a trade-off between render speed and image realism.

I would suggest to turn down each number of bounces to 0, just so you see what happens then. Then start increasing one of the numbers, and see how it affects your image. The aim is to keep the numbers as low as possible (to get a fast render) while keeping them high enough so that the image looks the way you want it to.

Comment: Ok.Thanks.In particulary what causes "fireflies")

Comment: Those appear because Cycles randomly samples your scene by shooting "rays" into it and letting those bounce around. If such a ray happens to bounce straight into a lamp, you'll get a white pixel. If it doesn't, you get a darker pixel. With only one sample per pixel you'll clearly see those white pixels. With more samples Cycles can take the average and smoothen them out, removing the fireflies. You may want to read through [7 Ways to Get Rid of Fireflies](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/).

Comment: @Andrea this site is not a forum, for new questions please use the [Ask Question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link at the top right of the page.