# How to choose the correct number of bounces in the light paths for photorealism?

Tags: lighting, photorealism

I would like to know how the max bounce works in the scene settings, and how to set the values of the different parameters (diffuse, brightness, transparency, transmission, and volume) for photorealistic applications.

Comment: There is a *Full GI* preset (accessible via light paths panel), https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76878/what-values-should-i-use-for-light-paths

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot
Sorry I did not find this post

Comment: Glad I could help @Noella